# How to validate client id for given access token?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am working on one spring boot application which is secured with oauth2. User can only access the API endpoints when they have valid access tokens from sso authorization server(which is remote service). I am checking the scope of the given token for accessing particular API endpoint. But many services have same scopes hence the token generated by one client id can access the endpoints of other who have similar scope. Hence I want to also validate the given token is generated by the client id of registered service.How can I do it?
My resource server endpoint is as follows:

```
.antMatchers("/agent/{agentId}").access("(#oauth2.hasScope('Chatagent-message')")
```

So my application checks the scope of validated token and gives the access. But I want to also check whether the token is generated by given client id.

I have agentId and client id mapping at my application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security OAUTH2 - How to restrict access to APIs based on client ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66208376/spring-security-oauth2-how-to-restrict-access-to-apis-based-on-client-id)